# Merge Intervals/Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'

Tags: c++, vector

leetcode question-->I've to mearge the commom/overlaping intervals
can anyone help why this error is comming.
Question link-https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/

MY code is

```
    class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        vector<vector<int>>ans;
        int n = intervals.size();
        ans[0][0] = intervals[0][0];
        ans[0][1] = intervals[0][1];
        int i=0,j=1;
        while(j<n ){
            if(ans[i][1] > intervals[j][0]){
                //ans[i][0] = intervals[i][0];
                ans[i][1] = intervals[j][1];
                j++;
            }
            else{
                i=i+1;
                ans[i][0] = intervals[j][0];
                ans[i][1] = intervals[j][1];
                j++;
            }
            
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You might want to ensure `ans` has some elements before trying to access them

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to choose a better title for your question. Secondly, I believe your algorithm does not meet the whole possible condition; if there's a set of intervals like {[2,3], [1,6]}, your algorithm merges these intervals to [2,6]. So, it is better to have some revise on your algorithm.

Comment: sorry for the bad title .and yess you are correct my code will not work for your input . BUT why I am getting runTime error. It must give me wrong output  for some test case If you can explain this??

Answer (score 0):

- For solving this problem, we would want to sort the intervals first (order of N Log N).
- This'll get through:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
    static const std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge(
            std::vector<std::vector<int>>& intervals
    ) {
        std::sort(std::begin(intervals), std::end(intervals));
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> merged;

        if (std::size(intervals) >= 1) {
            merged.emplace_back(intervals[0]);
        }

        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < std::size(intervals); ++index) {
            const std::vector<int> interval = intervals[index];
            const std::vector<int> tail = merged.back();

            if (tail[1] >= interval[0]) {
                merged.pop_back();
                merged.emplace_back(std::vector<int> {
                    std::min(tail[0], interval[0]),
                    std::max(interval[1], tail[1])
                });

            } else {
                merged.emplace_back(interval);
            }
        }

        return merged;
    }

};
```